# row multiplication in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How to implement the following SQL query using Hibernate Criteria API:

```
SELECT
    SUM(field1) as s,
    SUM(field1 * field2) as m
FROM 
    table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
add(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(field1)) AS s", new String[] { "s" }, new Type[] {Hibernate.DOUBLE }))
add(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(field1*field2) AS m", new String[] { "m" }, new Type[] {Hibernate.DOUBLE }))
```

Comment: Maybe you want to explain why?